# Validation for max Int , max long values

Tags: java, rest, validation, exception, dto

I am writing rest api where we are accepting dto in RequestBody, dto has field whose data type is int. What I want to achieve is, when user tries to enter value more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, I want to give error as "Value must be less than 2147483648". I tried validating dto using

```
@Max(value = Integer.MAX_VALUE, message = "Code must be less than 2147483648")
private int code;
```

where @Max is from javax.validation.constraints.Max.

But Iam getting ,

> JSON parse error: Numeric value (2147483648) out of range of int;
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Numeric value
>   (2147483648) out of range of int.

So is there any other annotation by which we can achieve this, or do I have to do it via exception handling?

Comment: @Sambit , no it does not answer my question.

Comment: This validation won't work, because it is impossible to assign a larger value to a field of type `int`, so the validation you added will never fire. You'd need to make the field type `long` to be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

An `int`, by definition can only handle up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Anyway, another idea could be to design the dto `int` to be a `long` value so that the value can be always converted, no matter how large the communicated value is.

With the current validation in place this value is also in range that it can be mapped to `int` for positive values.
However, this is a design decision.

Just another hint: The validation as I see it foresees positive values, but what about negative ones?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not work exactly like that. The issue is, that it never reaches validation. And it never will. First of all it tries to parse it and insert value in to `int`. Since it is too big, it fails to map it. If you were to put any other value, it would reach validation.

I am afraid that you are correct and the only other way is to handle exceptions.

1. If you are using Spring, you could use `@ControllerAdvice` to
   achieve desired functionality. [Controller Advice docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)
2. Or you could maybe use [BindingResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) which would provide you with errors that happened and you could then handle them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider making the code field as String? When trying to validate the input data provided, you can use BigInteger to verify if the value passed-in is within the range that you were expecting.

```
 if (new BigInteger(value).compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) > 0
        || new BigInteger(value).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

This will also give you the control to convert the data to either int or long based on your requirements. By using String for IDs, you are eliminating the scenario of maxing out the limit of a data type.